# Game Center Friend List

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-center

All

I made a game for the Apple iOS. Now I would like to show my friend list in Apple's Game Center.

How can I show the Game Center friend list of a logged in player on an iPhone, possibly using the UIViewController (which manages the ViewControllers)?

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show your Game center friends in your app you can use the below code given.

```
     -(void) retrieveFriends
   {
          GKLocalPlayer *lp = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]; 
          if (lp.authenticated)   
         { 
             [lp loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *friends, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (friends != nil)
                 {
                      [self loadPlayerData: friends];
                 }

             }];

         }

    }



       -(void) loadPlayerData: (NSArray *) identifiers
        {
             [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:identifiers withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) 
           {

              if (error != nil) 
                {
                  // Handle the error.
                } 
             if (players != nil) 
               {
          // Process the array of GKPlayer objects.
               } 
           }];

          }
```

For more reference you can use the Apple Game KIT guide. below is the link to it

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Hope it helps..

Comment: What is LoadPlayerData ?
And i have done this one and get this log
2011-12-01 11:24:57.118 XXXXXX[620:207] Firneds List (
"G:407117641",
"G:1438469299",
"G:1446159777"

What should i do with this id ?
i need to display as like we see in Apple Game center app friend tab...

Comment: @Jagdish i have updated my answer.. and i highly recommend you to go through the Apple gameKit Documents.

Comment: yes why not. just save the list in an array and iterate it in UITaleView. but it is preferable to use a separate UIViewController for GameCenter, where you can show your active player, their scores and everything else...If you find my above answer as helpful pls mark it as correct..

Comment: your answer is good, but not enough.. Have you any example relate to showing friend list in ViewController.. ?

Comment: @Jagdish I think you have not gone through the GameKit documentation. Show us your effort then SO will help you to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

For a single Block:

```
-(void)loadPlayerData:(void (^)(NSArray * playerObjects))complete
{
    GKLocalPlayer *lp = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    if (lp.authenticated)
    {
        [lp loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *friends, NSError *error)
         {
             if (friends != nil)
             {
                 [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:friends withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error)
                  {

                      if (error != nil)
                      {
//                            return @[error];
                          // Handle the error.
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          complete (players);

                      }
                  }];
             }
         }];
    }
}
```