# iOS: can game center account somehow be used for authentication on custom webservice?

Tags: ios, game-center, backend

Let's say we wan to have a custom backend for a iOS game that manages user accounts and allows the users to send objects to each other, but we don't want to actually have the user to create a dedicated useraccount for our game. It would be possible to simply use the playerID for the usermanagement, but that would not be secure. Is there any way to use a local gamecenter authentication to also authenticate at a custom webservice?

Currently i ponder about how the game 'pocket frogs' enables the players to send gifts to gamecenter friends. Gamecenter doesn't seem to provide this functionality so i assume they use a custom backend for it, but how can such a backend authenticate the player?

Comment: Can't say I know the answer to this, but I'm interested in trying something similar some time.  Could custom challenges be used for this?

Comment: problem with this is that it will show up in gamecenter as challenge

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure if this is how Pocket Frogs (PF) does it, but based on the fact that only Game Center (GC) friends who also play PF appear on the neighbours list, I think it may work like this:

When a player first starts the game, they get a user id (a 32-bit int, say) from the PF back end which is stored locally.  Once the player has this id it can be stored in one of the GC leaderboards under the GKScore `context` property rather than the `value`.  As far as I can see, PF automatically adds every player to all of the leaderboards pretty much straight away.

Then when another player wants to send a gift, PF gets the leaderboard scores for all of their GC friends and if they have a valid score they must be a PF player and the `context` value can be read to get their PF id.

In this way the PF back end gets the correct id, but doesn't need to use their GC id.

Incidentally, I tried out the idea of using challenges for sending gifts, and it can work.  See http://www.lrgdigital.com/ofgame.html for the game I tried it with - you have to win a game before you can gift it.  It has the benefit that you can send the gift to anyone on your friends list rather than only friends who play the game, but there are some limitations as well.

Answer (score 0):

No. Gamecenter uses apple id and that is off limits for obvious reasons. And if you look into the game center framework, there is a way to get gamecenter friends.

Look here to see how to get an array of friends: [Game Center Friend List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336971/game-center-friend-list)

Comment: Yes it's possible to get the friendslist, but it's not possible to send objects (messages) to them without starting a turnbased match (which will show up as such in gamecenter). So i wonder how pocket frogs can send frogs to game center friends